# Blackberry Scroll issue

Tags: html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have created a HTML page for Blackberry. I have done all right but am not able to scroll any divisions using trackpad.

I am testing this in Blackberry bold.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,target-  densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1.0">
<title>XXXX</title>
</head>
<body class="Claimtype">
<div class="mainwrapper">
<header>
<h1>Claim Type<span></span></h1>
</header>
<article>
<div class="claimtype_content">
  <div class="claim_summary">
    <h3>
      <label>Plan No:</label>
      183245</h3>
    <h4>Health Spending account</h4>
    <h4>Health Spending account</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="claim_type_selection">
    <h3>Type of Claim</h3>
    <select name="claim_type_selection">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Select2</option>
      <option>Select3</option>
      <option>Select4</option>
      <option>Select5</option>
    </select>
    <div class="claimtype_desc">
        <div class="claimdescimg">
            <img src="inputUser.png" width="50" height="50">
        </div>
      <div class="claimtype_desctxt">
      <h3>Dental</h3>
          <p>The following notes and warnings highlight missing or conflicting information which caused the validator to perform some guesswork prior to validation. The following notes and warnings highlight missing or conflicting information which caused the validator to perform some guesswork prior to validation. The following notes and warnings highlight missing or conflicting information which caused the validator to perform some guesswork prior to validation.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I want to scroll "claimtype_desctxt" text where I have also added overflow styles.

Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you need to know is summarized here:

[Using focus-based navigation](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_developing/using_the_navigation_mode_1866978_11.html)

1st- Specifying the navigation mode in the configuration file:

```
<widget>
    <rim:navigation mode=â€�focusâ€�/>
    <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" />
</widget>
```

2nd- Defining focusable elements, here's the example:

```
<img id="image1" src="imageb.png" x-blackberry-focusable="true" />
```

You can also define initial focus:

```
<a class="list" x-blackberry-initialFocus="true">First element</a>
```

Here's the complete sample code with a javascript function that changes highlight style of focused objects:

```
<html>
<head>

   <title>Color Input Type</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function highlight(e) {
         e.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red; outline: cyan solid thick;");
      }

      function unhighlight(e) {
         e.setAttribute("style", "");
      }
   </script>
</head>

<body>    
   <h2>Test input type - text/password/email/search/tel/number</h2>
      <div>
         <label >Text: </label>
         <input type="text" x-blackberry-focusable="true" onmouseover="highlight(this);" 
            onmouseout="unhighlight(this);" />
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Number: </label>
         <input type="number" x-blackberry-focusable="true" onmouseover="highlight(this);" 
            onmouseout="unhighlight(this);" />
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Answers really ought to contain some real content, rather than just links elsewhere: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers